# pytest monkeypatch terminal size

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm playing with the monkeypatch fixture in pytest, trying to mock the current size of the terminal window.

```
import os
import pytest

def get_terminal_size():
    terminal_size = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read()
    return terminal_size

def test_get_terminal_size(monkeypatch):
    # The get_terminal_size() function will return a string 'height width\n'
    def mock_size():
        return '10 20\n'

    monkeypatch.setattr(os.popen('stty size', 'r'), 'read', mock_size)

    assert get_terminal_size() == '10 20\n'
```

When I run pytest I get an assertion error:

```
__________________________________________________________________ test_get_terminal_size __________________________________________________________________

monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f5bf1ec0cf8>

    def test_get_terminal_size(monkeypatch):
        # The get_terminal_size() function will return a string 'height width\n'
        def mock_size():
            return '10 20\n'

        monkeypatch.setattr(os.popen('stty size', 'r'), 'read', mock_size)

>       assert get_terminal_size() == '10 20\n'
E       AssertionError: assert '' == '10 20\n'
E         + 10 20

test_monkeypatch.py:15: AssertionError
```

So it looks like it isn't setting the mock_size. I've tried following the pattern in the [pytest documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043143/how-to-fake-popen-in-test)

Any suggestions on getting this to work?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
As pointed out by Kent Shikama in the answer below, for the way I was attempting to capture the output I needed to be using the -s flag to turn off pytest capturing.

But with further research about the usage of popen, specifically, the migration from using os.popen to subprocess.Popen, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module), and some help from this [S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043143/how-to-fake-popen-in-test) on "How to fake Popen" I've come up with a solution.

here is the new setup:

```
# \mokeypatch_popen.py
from subprocess import Popen

def get_terminal_size():
    terminal_size = Popen('stty size', shell=True)
    return terminal_size
```

The test function:

```
# \test_monkeypatch.py
import pytest
import monkeypatch_popen

def test_get_terminal_size(monkeypatch):
    # The get_terminal_size() function will return a string 'height width\n'
    def mock_terminal_size(cmd, **kwargs):
        return '10 20\n'

    monkeypatch.setattr(m_patch, 'Popen' , mock_terminal_size)

    assert m_patch.get_terminal_size() == '10 20\n'
```

Not obvious to me at first was the fact that the mock_terminal_size function will be processing the parameters of the Popen method it is mocking, therefore it must accept the parameters used by Popen in the original function. I could have specifically added the shell parameter to mock_terminal_size, but since Popen accepts a long list of kwargs I was a bit more ambiguous.

This now passes when I run pytest and the -s flag is not necessary as I'm no longer attempting to capture an output, but mocking the execution of the Popen method.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to run pytest with the `-s` flag or else stty will be captured. And then you should get the assertion error you were probably expecting as follows:

```
>       assert get_terminal_size() == '10 20\n'
E       AssertionError: assert '24 80\n' == '10 20\n'
E         - 24 80
E         + 10 20
```

It sounds like you want to mock the read method on the stream such that it always runs "10 20". Usually you would do something like

```
from io import TextIOWrapper
monkeypatch.setattr(TextIOWrapper, 'read', mock_size)
```

but unfortunately you can't mock a builtin object. You could try something like [forbiddenfruit](https://pypi.org/project/forbiddenfruit/) to overcome this but it feels like you might want to change your approach.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I looked into changing my approach and updated the post with my findings. It does seem like you can mock builtin objects, but the preferred method is to mock the object specific to the function you are testing to localize the scope i.e. `monkeypatch(func.Object, 'method', mock_func`.